# How to disconnect an existing ruby sequel connection to a database?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I mean the one which was previously established as

```
DB = Sequel.sqlite('my_blog.db')
```

or

```
DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://user:password@localhost/my_db')
```

or

```
DB = Sequel.postgres('my_db', :user => 'user', :password => 'password', :host => 'localhost')
```

or etcetera.

The Sequel::Database class has no public instance method called "disconnect" or so though it has "connect" one.

Maybe somebody already faced that problem. I would appreciate any idea.

Comment: Doesn't this work: http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Database.html#M000332

It's not logical for the `disconnect` method to be class method BTW.

Comment: It works, but it disconnects all of the established connections instead of the one, although that method is of public instance kind

Comment: You're right, I meant public instance method. Corrected. Thanks

Comment: Which one? `DB` is a `Database`, not a `Connection`. Sequel's connection pools have `disconnect` method as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Mladen Jablanović points out, you can just do:

```
DB.disconnect
```

Which will disconnect all of the available connections in that Sequel::Database instance's connection pool.  You can't choose a specific connection to disconnect, and it wouldn't make sense to.  The sharded connection pools do support disconnecting all connections for a specific shard, though.

Comment: After you told that wouldn't make sense, I started to doubt that I understand connection pools right. The following code assumes that multiple modules can simultaneously use specific connection from DB hash:
[[[ DB = {}; DB[:a] Sequel.postgres('a', opts); DB[:b] Sequel.postgres('b', opts); DB[:c] Sequel.postgres('c', opts) ]]].
The task is in disconnecting all the DB[:a] connections, actually in releasing the specific database. Is the above approach right? Is that possible? DB[:a].disconnect doesn't work as desired, or I do misunderstand?
BTW, many thanks for the toolkit!

Comment: Sorry for the ugly message, I'm not yet unaccustomed to Stackoverflow's methods. The example code and clarifications should probably be in a question((

Comment: You don't ever get to choose a specific connection to use.  Assuming that DB[:a] is your Sequel::Database, DB[:a].disconnect will disconnect all available connections in DB[:a]'s connection pool.  If you have more questions, you may want to post on Sequel's Google Group with the code you are using.